# How to write a program to ask the user for an input between 1-20 but it prints "invalid input" if user enters any char or string or (-ve) integers?

Tags: c, while-loop, numbers, range, scanf

I am working on a simple project of C-Programming called "Election System". But i want to optimize it so the output will never be wrong. So for this i need this:-
**How to write a program to ask the user for an input between 1-20 but it prints "invalid input" if user enters "any character or string or negative integers"?**

And please explain your code while giving the answer it would be really appreciated.

So far i didn't tried anything. I could not think of logic for character or string input
for negative number its easy.

Comment: Enter using `fgets()`. If you can't extract a valid number from the string, repeat. Use a buffer that is quite a lot bigger than you think you need. Unless the input is *guaranteed* to meet the input spec it's quite difficult using `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like the following

```
const unsigned int MIN = 1;
const unsigned int MAX = 20;

unsigned int value = 0;

do
{
    printf( "Enter a value in the range [%u, %u]: ", MIN, MAX );

    if (scanf( "%u", &value ) != 1 || value < MIN || MAX < value )
    {
        puts( "Invalid input." );
        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
        value = 0;
    }
} while ( value < MIN || MAX < value );
```

If the user will enter an invalid number

```
if (scanf( "%u", &value ) != 1 || value < MIN || MAX < value )
```

then the inner while loop

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
```

skips invalid characters in the input buffer.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int MIN = 1;
    const unsigned int MAX = 20;

    unsigned int value = 0;

    do
    {
        printf( "Enter a value in the range [%u, %u]: ", MIN, MAX );

        if (scanf( "%u", &value ) != 1 || value < MIN || MAX < value )
        {
            puts( "Invalid input." );
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            value = 0;
        }
    } while (value < MIN || MAX < value);

    printf( "value = %u\n", value );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a value in the range [1, 20]: Hello
Invalid input.
Enter a value in the range [1, 20]: 21
Invalid input.
Enter a value in the range [1, 20]: 20
value = 20
```

However the approach has one drawback. An input like that

```
20 A
```

will be correct because the call of `scanf` successfully will read the number `20` from the input buffer.

Another and more reliable approach is to use standard functions `fgets` and `strtol`. But its implementation can be more complicated if you do not want to allow such input like

```
20 A
```

Comment: can i use fflush(stdin); instead of while ( getchar() != '\n' );

Comment: @Md_Adnan fflush( stdin) has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Md_Adnan: I suggest that you read this question: [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/12149471)

Comment: If `getchar` for some reason returns `EOF`, then the line `while (getchar() != '\n');` will be an infinite loop. Therefore, it would probably be better to also check for `EOF` in that loop. However, I am still upvoting the answer, because OP is unlikely to run into that problem.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks. I think he needs a very simple code that performs the task.:)